# How to add bootstrap wysiwyg into flask?

Tags: python, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I want to using  [bootstrap wysiwyg](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) in my `Flask` website.
I found this project [flask-wysiwyg](https://github.com/TCnet/flask-wysiwyg) and followed the author's advise, but it doesn't work.

I would like to know:

- What is wrong?
- How should I solve this by myself?

Here is the code:

form.py

```
from .wysiwyg import WysiwygField

class PostForm(Form):
    article_title = StringField(u'title', validators=[Required(), Length(1, 64)])
    body = WysiwygField(u"txteditor", validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField(u'submit')
```

view.py

```
# views.py
from .forms import PostForm
@main.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post():
    title = u'edit'
    form = PostForm()
    if  form.validate_on_submit():
        posts = Post(article_title=form.article_title.data,
                     body=form.body.data,
                     author=current_user._get_current_object())
        db.session.add(posts)
        flash(u'commit')
        return redirect(url_for('.doc'))
    return render_template('post-rich-text-edit.html', title=title, form=form)
```

post-rich-text-edit.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='prettify.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='font-awesome.css') }}">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method=post action="/">
            {{ form.article_title }}
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.body.label }}
                <div id="editor">
                {{ form.body(size=20) }}

                </div>
            {{ form.submit }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-wysiwyg.js') }}"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.hotkeys.js') }}"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='prettify.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Please include the full traceback.

Comment: it can't edit in my editor..there is a simple but can't write anything.@Forge

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what are the issues you are facing. However, you have a point that the documentation of the [`flask-wysiwyg`](https://github.com/TCnet/flask-wysiwyg) package might be misleading.

To use `WysiwygField`, change your `import statement` in `forms.py` to:

```
from flask_wysiwyg.wysiwyg import WysiwygField
```

Comment: Thanks. and it doesn't work either.[This is my editor](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img921/7231/69JBg2.png) BUT can't edit, can't write anything.

Comment: @Abirdcfly please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

add `WysiwygField` to `forms.py`

```
from flask_wysiwyg.wysiwyg import WysiwygField
```

and add to `block scripts` in `post-rich-text-edit.html`

```
<script>
    $('#editor').wysiwyg();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the last 3 lines in `scripts block` to `head block`